# Find the rows that has the same column

Tags: sql, postgresql, doctrine

I want to know how to do the following in SQL :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_A 
WHERE id IN(:myValues)
AND other_colum has the same value
```

For example, if i've a conversation table(iduser,idconversation), I want SQL query that returns some of Ids that have the same conversation id. It should return

```
35;105
37;105
35;106
37;106
```

With 35,37 the idUsers and 105,106 the conversations they have in common.

To go further, i work with **Doctrine and PostegreSQL**, and the table that I want to query is generated **(many to many relation)** but i've difficulty to integrate sub-query.

```
  **public function getAllCommonConversationByUserId($ids)
  {
      return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
          ->select('c.id')
          ->innerJoin('c.idUser', 'recievedConversation')
          ->where('recievedConversation IN (:ids)')
          ->andWhere('$qb->expr()->eq("SELECT id FROM table GROUP BY(id) HAVING COUNT(*) >1")')
          ->setParameter(':ids', $ids)
          ->getQuery()
          ->getResult();
  }**
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I use PostgreSQL and doctrine

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_A 
WHERE idconversation in ('105','106') and iduser in ('35','37')
```

**UPDATE:**
Are you saying if the idconversation is duplicate? (showing multiple times?)

If so:

```
Select * 
From table 
where idconversation in 
(
Select idconversation 
From table
group by (idconversation)
Having count(*) >1
)
--where iduser in ('35','37')
```

Comment: Without to tell the ids of conversation. I just have to tell idUser and SQL has to return me the idConversation they have in common

Comment: Yes, it's what i want. I'm using Doctrine and i didn't manage to do it (because of the subquery integration)

Comment: I am not familiar with that product, sorry:(

Answer (score 0):

You can get the conversations using `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT conversationid
FROM table_A 
WHERE userid in (35, 37)
GROUP BY userid
HAVING count(distinct userid) = 2;
```

If you want the original rows, you can join back to the original table.

Comment: are 35 and 37 users id in your query or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
select id, conversation
from [your table name]
where 
    conversation in (
        select conversation 
        from [your table name]
        where id in (35)
    )
```

It return all of the participants of the conversation with user id = 35

If you have duplicates in your table, please add **distinct** to select statement.